# Singularity, AnnotSV and HPO

Tags: singularity

I am trying to use [AnnotSV](https://lbgi.fr/AnnotSV/) to annotate some Manta outputs in the following code with the [HPO term](https://hpo.jax.org/app/) changed:

Where:

- input_dir is the input directory
- singularity_container is the path to the AnnotSV singularity container

```bash
# Loop through the files in the input directory
for file in "$input_dir"/*.vcf; do
    # Get the base name of the file without extension
    filename=$(basename "$file" .vcf)

    # Create the output subdirectory within the input directory
    output_dir="$input_dir/AnnotSV_Batch_Run"
mkdir -p "$output_dir"

    # Set the output file path with "_AnnotSV" appended
    output_file="$output_dir/${filename}_AnnotSV_"

    # Run AnnotSV via Singularity with the base name as output prefix
    singularity exec "$singularity_container" AnnotSV -SVinputFile "$file" -genomeBuild GRCh38 --hpo "HP:0000001"  -outputFile "$output_file"
done
```

The HPO term I am using is in the jax.org site but when I run it - I get the most peculiar error  `option not known.` but the HPO term is specified in the [AnnotSV manual](https://lbgi.fr/AnnotSV/Documentation/README.AnnotSV_latest.pdf) on page 49 (according to the number on the bottom). As for trying I tried with `--HPOterm` and `hpoterm` I tried with and without the `:` and with and without quotes as well. I am not sure what the issue is but I cannot seem to find the solution. Has anyone perchance used this software before with HPO terms as it seems not to be accepting the input I give it?

Comment: The manual says `-hpo` and you're using `--hpo`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Now I am getting `"/usr/local/share/AnnotSV/Annotations_Human/Genes/GRCh38/refGene.txt.gz" file doesn't exist`
Please check your install - Exit with error.?

Comment: Try adding a `--no-mount` flag immediately after `singularity exec` in the command.

Comment: The --no-mount gives the error `FATAL:   "--no-mount": executable file not found in $PATH` - I also tried with `usr/local/bin/AnnotSV` and it did not work

Comment: Oops, my bad. I did not read the documentation properly, sorry. Try `singularity exec --no-mount hostfs AnnotSV`

Comment: This error is persistent and I am not sure how to get around it.

Comment: Is this the page from which you're getting the singularity image link: https://lbgi.fr/AnnotSV/downloads

Comment: Try downloading the annotations file, uncompressing it and providing it as an input to the `-annotationsDir` parameter. The base image, which is ~400 MB seems to contain only the executable and all the images I see on docker hub are at least 4 gigs, which makes me think they include some sort of resource file that the base image does not have.

Comment: Yes the singularity is from the link

Comment: I believe I am doing this incorrectly as I give it the folder of the `phenotype_to_genes.txt` that I got from HPO but it seems like it still gives `command not found` for a lot this is only part of the error ```/usr/local/etc/AnnotSV/configfile: line 9: -annotationMode:: command not found
/usr/local/etc/AnnotSV/configfile: line 11: -benignAF:: command not found
/usr/local/etc/AnnotSV/configfile: line 13: -candidateGenesFiltering:: command not found
/usr/local/etc/AnnotSV/configfile: line 15: -genomeBuild:: command not found
```

Comment: The folder I gave was under the annotationsDir flag but the error persists.

Comment: Something is interfering with the shell parsing your command. Add an `echo` in front of the singularity command, then add a `set -x` before the for loop begins. Run the script and paste the output on pastebin, then link to the pastebin content here.

Comment: What is pastebin?

Comment: Did you Google it?

Comment: I did - it seems that AnnotSV doesn't work well with Singularity so this could not be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that currently AnnotSV does not support HPO terms usage an Singularity.